# Segmentation Fault in pthreads, Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm getting a Segmentation Fault when I run this code. Surprisingly, when I set `thread_count` to 16 or less, it doesn't give any error. When I debug the code using gdb, the code gets an error at line `local_answer += vec_1[j] * vec_2[j];` in the `Calculate()` thread function. What is the reason for this behavior? How can I fix that?

I'm compiling with this gcc command:

```
gcc test.c -o DP -lpthread -lm -mcmodel=large -g
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

double *vec_1 = NULL;
double *vec_2 = NULL;
int vec_length = 0;
int thread_count = 0;
double answer = 0;
double *partial_results = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *Calculate(void *arg) {    
    int myId = (int) arg;
    int myStart = myId * vec_length / thread_count;
    int myEnd = (myId + 1) * vec_length / thread_count;

    double local_answer = 0;
    int j;

    for(j = myStart; j < myEnd; j++) {
        local_answer += vec_1[j] * vec_2[j];
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    partial_results[myId] = local_answer;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {    
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL)); 
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    int num_iterations = 5;

    vec_length = 1000000000;  
    thread_count = 25;

    partial_results = (double*) malloc(thread_count * sizeof(double)); 

    double avg_time = 0;
    int i;

    vec_1 = (double*) malloc(vec_length * sizeof(double)); 
    vec_2 = (double*) malloc(vec_length * sizeof(double));

    if(vec_1==NULL || vec_2==NULL){
        printf("Memory Allocation failed");
        exit(0);
    }

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < vec_length; j++) {
        vec_1[j] = ((double) rand() / (double) (RAND_MAX)) + 1;
        vec_2[j] = ((double) rand() / (double) (RAND_MAX)) + 1;             
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_iterations; i++) {
        pthread_t threads[thread_count];
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        void* status;       
        struct timeval t1, t2;
        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

        int t;
        for (t = 0; t < thread_count; t++) {            
            if (pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, Calculate, (void*)(t))) {
                printf("ERROR in pthread_create()");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }

        pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

        answer = 0;
        for (t = 0; t < thread_count; t++) {            
            if (pthread_join(threads[t], &status)) {
                printf("ERROR in pthread_join()");
                exit(-1);
            }
            answer += partial_results[t];
        }

        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);     
        avg_time += (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;
    }

    printf("Average time Spent : %lf \n", avg_time / num_iterations);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must check that `vec_1` and `vec_2` are not `NULL` from `malloc`. IDK if it is true with Linux, but my version of MSVC cannot allocate enough memory for `1000000000` doubles. But you should check their value anyway.

Comment: Yes, even if your system is prepared to allow your process in excess of 16 GB of memory, it might be unwilling or unable to provide contiguous chunks 8 GB in size.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I edited my code and tested. Yet the error still exists. When compiling using gcc, if we use -mcmodel=large , it allows us to create large arrays

Comment: Also, your code is over-engineered.  Pthreads are joinable by default, so you don't need to create a thread attribute object just to specify that.  And you don't need that mutex, either, because none of the worker threads access the same vector elements as another, and thread start and thread joining provide sufficient synchronization with the main program.

Comment: It was an "aside" comment, not an answer!

Comment: @JohnBollinger What you say is true. Yet the code runs perfectly when I reduce the thread_count to 16, with the same array size. How can you explain that?

Comment: When I can explain that, @Pasindu, I'll likely write it up as an answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I used that mutex to avoid false sharing condition.

Comment: @Pasindu, false sharing is a *performance* issue, not a correctness issue.  You have addressed that potential performance problem by making your code *even slower* than it would be if false sharing were indeed an issue, and by making it more complicated to boot.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah... I can't see much wrong with it either:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `vec_length` has type `int`.  With gcc on Linux x86 or x86_64, `int` is represented in 32-bit two's complement format.  This is sufficient to accommodate the value you're using for `vec_length`, 1,000,000,000, but *not* to accommodate most integer multiples of that value.  You compute several such multiples, and the resulting overflow of a signed integer formally produces undefined behavior.

In practice, it is likely that gcc's actual behavior upon signed integer overflow is reproducible.  In that case, you can write a program to demonstrate for yourself that the results are negative for several small-integer multiples of your vector length.  Where that occurs, your program will attempt to access outside the bounds of each of the two vectors, at the line where indeed the error is indicated, with a segfault being a likely result.  (And even if the overflow results were *not* reproducible, obtaining a negative result for some of those undefined multiplication behaviors would still be well within the realm of possibility.)

You have several alternatives, among them:

- use a wider data type for your indexing computations

  ```
  int myStart = myId * (int64_t) vec_length / thread_count;
  ```
- use only `thread_count` values that evenly divide the `vec_length`, and use parentheses to ensure that the division is performed first in your indexing computations

  ```
  int myStart = myId * (vec_length / thread_count);
  // ...
  vec_length = 1000000000;
  thread_count = 32;  // or 10 or 8 or 1000
  ```

---

A few other things:

- The code presented does not use any math.h functions.  It therefore does not need to `#include` math.h, and you do not need to link in libm.
- To compile a Pthreads program with GCC, you ought to use the `-pthreads` flag, in which case you also do not need to explicitly link in libpthread.
- As discussed in comments, you do not need the complication of a `pthread_attr_t`.
- As discussed in comments, your particular use of a mutex is an unnecessary performance drain.

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing the counter variable type to long long solved the issue.

Comment: Well spotted, have an upboat:)